# where put a JPA persistence.xml in a web application

Tags: web-applications, jpa, configuration, web-deployment

I exercise myself in J2EE programming: I modified the source file of [*converter*'s exampl](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipss.html)e of J2EE tutorial of Oracle, putting JPA code in it and deploying in GlassFish.

Using the exiting ANT configuration, I compile and deploy correctly, but at runtime the system don't find the *persistence.xml*.

This is the structure of deployed files[image]. I put in more place the same file xml for eluding the problem, but unsuccessfully.

In *server.log*, I find

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence
>   provider for EntityManager named test

The JPA is supported by Glassfish (I don't receive a ClassnotFoundException of NoDefClassError, the I have'nt any classpath problem), the id of persistence is unique, and the instruction causing the exception is

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test")
```

This is my *persistence.xml* configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>converter2.ejb.Converter2Bean</class>
    <class>entity.Order</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JPA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="my_password"/>
      <property name="default-schema" value="JPA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="C:\\mysql\\crea.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I put the:

- hibernate-testing.jar
- hibernate3.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

in the directory *\glassfish3\glassfish\lib\db* and I restarted Glassfish.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: The application is  an EAR, not a WAR

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises from Glassfish not being able to find Hibernate classes, put them in the *lib/ext* folder under your domain folder (example: */glassfish3/glassfish/domain/yourdomain/lib/ext*) and restart Glassfish.

Comment: I put the libraries: hibernate, antlr, commons-collections, dom4j, javassist, jta e slf4j-api in *WEB-INF/hibernate* of deployed application but the problem persists

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested in my answer? The *WEB-INF/hibernate is not in the application server classpath and so it's not a solution.

Comment: I tried: before I put the libraries in *glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext* but I receive still the ** javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager**

Comment: Are you sure the class *org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence* is in one of the jars you mention, I've done a search with google and it seems it's contained in *hibernate-entitymanager.jar*